# Set a range using variables in Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, variables, range

I just want to use a variable as part of a range in Vba to select some data.
I looked into the forum and found similar posts, however none solved my problem.

I defined `MyVar` as:

```
MyVar = Sheets("working").Range("CQ3").Value
```

In this case MyVar = 5 and I want to add 1 because I'm skipping the headers on sheet.
Now I want to select from A2 to Column CN and use as Row MyVar + 1

so far I tried:

```
Sheets("working").Range("A2: CN & MyVar + 1").select

Sheets("working").Range("A2": CN "& MyVar + 1").select

Sheets("working").Range("A2": "CN & MyVar + 1").select

Sheets("working").Range("A" & 2: "CN" & MyVar + 1).select
```

and none is working

Thank you very much in advance for your appreciated support

Here is the code:

```
MyVar = Sheets("working").Range("CQ3").Value



Sheets("working").Range("A2: CN & MyVar + 1").select
Sheets("working").Range("A2": CN "& MyVar + 1").select
Sheets("working").Range("A2": "CN & MyVar + 1").select
Sheets("working").Range("A" & 2: "CN" & MyVar + 1).select


Selection.copy
Sheets("TOTALS").Select
Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
Sheets("working").Range("A2:CN" & (MyVar + 1)).Select
```

Additional brackets force the order of operations, so first `MyVar + 1` is calculated, then the result is appnded to a string indicating the range address.

[Also I'd avoid `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
Worksheets("working").Range("A2:CN" & (MyVar + 1)).Select
```

The constant part of your range address needs to be in enclosed in quotes `""` and the variable part needs to be concatenated with `&`. To ensure the calculating `+ 1` is done before concatenating you can enclose the variable part in parenthesis `()`.

And you might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).